# CSS Nav Background Image is not showing up

Tags: css

I would like to add an image to the Nav list on hover but it is not working!
can you please take a look at what I have here 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/933W9/)

```
enter code here
body{background-color:#2D2D2D;}
#nav {
width: 50%;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 3em 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
     }
    #nav li {
float: left; 
     }
    #nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #069;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    #nav li :hover{
background: url(http://www.demosphere.com/images/stories/glossy-light-bulb.jpg) no-repeat center top;
opacity:0;
    }
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

because in this line 
background: url(http://www.demosphere.com/images/stories/glossy-light-bulb.jpg) no-repeat center top;

i think you are wrong in the property that you use the correct one is to use background-image

background-image: url(http://www.demosphere.com/images/stories/glossy-light-bulb.jpg) no-repeat center top;

Comment: Hi Oussaki, I update the code as you said but it still not working

Comment: I think that your Background is so big for that  try with another small than this ...  cuz i think you use a list and  an element of a list have a with and height for that maybe your background not showing .. good luck